# For each loop to retrieve multiple messages in page

Tags: javascript, html

For a Chrome plugin, I need to retrieve messages. These messages are supplied to me through an html variable.

There are 2 messages in the example provided below and they both start with: `<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">` and end with: `</tr>`

I retrieved the first message data, but now I need to make it so that it retrieves all the data from each of those `<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> </tr>` messages.

**What I get provided:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="xxx">
  <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body class="bodySinScrollHor">


  <table width="95%" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td class="etiquetaIzquierda" colspan=6>
        <a class="etiquetaIzquierda"><img border=0 height=15 src="xxx"> &nbsp;Comunicaciones (2)</a>
      </td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=6>
        <hr size=1 width="100%">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="comunicaciones">
      <td colspan=6>
        <table width="100%" border=0 bordercolor="#000000" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>

          <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <td width="9%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">2017-08-31T00:00:00</td>
            <td width="9%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">13:22</td>
            <td width="4%" align=left class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque">
              <img src="xxx" title=" Out"> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="11%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque" valign=top>
              <font class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque"><a title="clientname" class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque">ClientName</a></font>
            </td>
            <td width="14%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque" width="100%">Subject</td>
            <!--      <td width="61%"class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">message text here</td> -->
          </tr>

          <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <td width="9%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">2017-08-31T00:00:00</td>
            <td width="9%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">13:21</td>
            <td width="4%" align=left class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque">
              <img src="xxx" title=" Out"> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td width="11%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque" valign=top>
              <font class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque"><a title="clientname" class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque">ClientName</a></font>
            </td>
            <td width="14%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque" width="100%">Subject</td>
            <!--      <td width="61%"class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">Message Text Here</td> -->
          </tr>

      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Below is the code I run to retrieve the data from the first message. Note that there are 2 messages in this case, but there are people that have 54 messages so it needs to loop that many times. This part of the code:

```
var count = (html1.match(/<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Is what provides that number for me.

```js
matches[0].forEach(function(match, index) {
  var cleintcode = /<div\s*class="t_seg_codCliente">(.*?)<\/div>/.exec(match)[1];
  var cleintname = /<div\s*class="t_seg_nomCliente">(.*?)<\/div>/.exec(match)[1];
  var taxId = /<div\s*class="t_seg_nifCliente">(.*?)<\/div>/.exec(match)[1];
  var date = /<div\s*class="t_seg_fechaPresCliente">(.*?)<\/div>/.exec(match)[1];
  var state = /<div\s*class="t_seg_estadoCliente">(.*?)<\/div>/.exec(match)[1];
  var expirydate = /<div\s*class="t_seg_fechaCadCliente">(.*?)<\/div>/.exec(match)[1];
  var communications = /<div\s*class="t_seg_comCliente"><a .*;">(.*?)<\/a>/.exec(match)[1];
  var comclient = /<div\s*class="t_seg_comCliente"><a href="javaScript:popupComs\('(.*?)'/.exec(match)[1];
  var messages = "xxx" + comclient;

  var html1 = httpGet(messages);

  //console.log(html1);

  const cleanupDocString = html1.replace(/(?:<!--|-->)/gm, '');

  parser = new DOMParser();

  htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(cleanupDocString, "text/html");

  //console.log(htmlDoc);

  var communicationsvalue = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque")[0].textContent;

  if (communicationsvalue.indexOf('No existen comunicaciones asociadas a este cliente.') !== -1) {
    console.log("This chat does not contain any communiction!");
  } else {

    //Get count of regex matches. (amount of messages)
    var count = (html1.match(/<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">/g) || []).length;
    console.log(count);

    var comDate = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque")[0].textContent;
    var comTime = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque")[1].textContent;
    var comType = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('img')[1].src;
    var comClient = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].textContent;
    var comSubject = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque")[6].textContent;

    const element = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName('valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque')[7];

    var pulledMessage = element.innerHTML;

    var messageData = [{
        clientCode: cleintcode,
        clientName: cleintname,
        taxID: taxId,
        cleintDate: date,
        cleintState: state,
        cleintExpirydate: expirydate
      },
      {
        mesDate: comDate,
        mesTime: comTime,
        mesType: comType,
        mesClient: comClient,
        mesSubject: comSubject,
        mesText: pulledMessage
      }
    ];
    console.log(messageData);
  }
});
```

**The code above gives me this console log:**

```
1.  0:
 1. cleintDate:"31/08/17"
 2. cleintExpirydate:"29/11/17"
 3. cleintState:"Subject"
 4. clientCode:"xxxxxx"
 5. clientName:"clientName"
 6. taxID:""
 7. __proto__:Object
2.  1:
 1. mesClient:"ClientName"
 2. mesDate:"2017-08-31T00:00:00"
 3. mesSubject:"Subject "
 4. mesText:"Message text Here"
 5. mesTime:"13:22"
 6. mesType:"link"
 7. __proto__:Object
```

Note that array 0 should not change because these messages are from the same person. I just need to grab the second message as well. So I technically need a second array like array 1 containing the data from the second message.

**Wanted result:**

```
1.  0:
 1. cleintDate:"31/08/17"
 2. cleintExpirydate:"29/11/17"
 3. cleintState:"Subject"
 4. clientCode:"xxxxxx"
 5. clientName:"clientName"
 6. taxID:""
 7. __proto__:Object
2.  1:
 1. mesClient:"ClientName"
 2. mesDate:"2017-08-31T00:00:00"
 3. mesSubject:"Subject "
 4. mesText:"Message text Here"
 5. mesTime:"13:22"
 6. mesType:"link"
 7. __proto__:Object
3. 3:
 1. mesClient:"ClientName"
 2. mesDate:"2017-08-31T00:00:00"
 3. mesSubject:"Subject "
 4. mesText:"Message text Here"
 5. mesTime:"13:22"
 6. mesType:"link"
 7. __proto__:Object
```

I know I have to build a for loop, but I have no idea on how do this, so it looks for the second `<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> </tr>` after the first.

Content is slightly edited to hide personal information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may possibly do as follows;

```js
var data = '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> <html> <head> <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="xxx"> <title>Untitled</title> </head> <body class="bodySinScrollHor"> <table width="95%" align="center"> <tr> <td class="etiquetaIzquierda" colspan=6> <a class="etiquetaIzquierda"><img border=0 height=15 src="xxx"> &nbsp;Comunicaciones (2)</a> </td> </td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan=6> <hr size=1 width="100%"> </td> </tr> <tr id="comunicaciones"> <td colspan=6> <table width="100%" border=0 bordercolor="#000000" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0> <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <td width="9%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">2017-08-31T00:00:00</td> <td width="9%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">13:22</td> <td width="4%" align=left class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque"> <img src="xxx" title=" Out"> &nbsp; &nbsp; </td> <td width="11%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque" valign=top> <font class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque"><a title="clientname" class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque">ClientName</a></font> </td> <td width="14%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque" width="100%">Subject</td> <!-- <td width="61%"class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">message text here</td> --> </tr> <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> <td width="9%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">2017-08-31T00:00:00</td> <td width="9%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">13:21</td> <td width="4%" align=left class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque"> <img src="xxx" title=" Out"> &nbsp; &nbsp; </td> <td width="11%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque" valign=top> <font class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque"><a title="clientname" class="valorcampoSinTamFijoPeque">ClientName</a></font> </td> <td width="14%" class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque" width="100%">Subject</td> <!-- <td width="61%"class="valorCampoSinTamFijoPeque">Message Text Here</td> --> </tr> </td> </tr> </table> </td> </tr> </table> </body> </html>';

var adiv = document.createElement("div"),
    msgs = [],
    trs;

adiv.innerHTML = data;
trs = adiv.querySelectorAll('tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]');
trs.forEach(function(tr){
              var d = [];
              tr.querySelectorAll("td")
                .forEach(function(td){
                           var img = td.querySelector("img"),
                               src = img && img.attributes.getNamedItem("src").value;
                           d.push(src || td.textContent);
                         });
              msgs.push(d);
            });
console.log(msgs);
```

Comment: This is close but im missing a few pieces of information: 1. 0:Array(5)
1. 0:"2017-08-31T00:00:00"
2. 1:"13:22"
3. 2:"↵          ↵     "
4. 3:"clientname"
5. 4:"subject "
6. length:5
7. __proto__:Array(0)
2. 1:Array(5)
1. 0:"2017-08-31T00:00:00"
2. 1:"13:21"
3. 2:"↵          ↵     "
4. 3:"clientname "
5. 4:"subject"

Comment: I fixed 1 piece of information but the one with : ↵ ↵ is supposed to be a link with an image but i got no clue on how to change it so it grabs it in your code.

Comment: @Robbert Sorry i couldn't understand the problem mentioned in your first comment but happy to know you have fixed it. As per your second comment i have modified the above code to exclude the `<td>`s with `<img>` tags in them.. See if it helps.

Comment: Im sorry. I guess i didnt make it clear. The one before was good but it gave me the output of the image tag when i need the href. So i need the href of the <img> and the text from the <td>'s. Once again sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: @Robbert OK i have modified the code to pick up the value of the `src` attribute of the child `<img>` tags. I hope this is what you mean by href. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
var trs = $('tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]');
var output = [];
for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++){
var currentOutput = {};
currentOutput.cleintDate=trs.eq(i).find("td").eq(0).text();
//other properties like this
currentOutput.cleintExpirydate=trs.eq(i).find("td").eq(1).text();
//add all your required properties
output.push(currentOutput);
}
console.log(output)
```

Without jquery

```
var trs = document.querySelectorAll('tr[bgcolor="#FFFFFF"]');
    var output = [];
    for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++){
    var currentOutput = {};
    currentOutput.cleintDate=trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerText;
    //other properties like this
    currentOutput.cleintExpirydate=trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerText;
    //add all your required properties
    output.push(currentOutput);
    }
    console.log(output)
```

Comment: Throws me this error: getPagesSource.js:124 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at getPagesSource.js:124
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at DOMtoString (getPagesSource.js:62)
    at getPagesSource.js:143

Comment: You would need to use jquery for this.

Comment: I dont want to use Jquery because the whole plugin is running with Javascript. There is probably a way to do this with Javascript

Comment: I have updated my code without jquery. Please check. You would need to modify according to your properties this way.